# How i can create generator string with ONLY ONE special character?

Tags: php, string, character, generator

i want to create generator string with one special character. Just only one. Can u help me ?.

I tried searched the generator on the internet but i saw only generatorspecial characters with a lot of special characters i need "ONLY ONE SPECIAL CHARACTER".

PHP 7

Comment: What do you have so far and what is a "special character" exactly?

Comment: Share some code with us showing what you have attempted so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this, based on the function you're using:

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $specials = '!@#$%^&*()';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    // Removed one from length to maintain desired length
    // for special character addition
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length - 1; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    // Add the special character:
    $randomString .= $specials[rand(0, strlen($specials) - 1)];
    // Shuffle the returned string so the special is not always at the end
    return str_shuffle($randomString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried sth like that:

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```

Special character I mean: "!@#$%^&*()"